# Fractional moments of multivariate normal distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, integration, fractional-calculus, moments

Is there an analytic formula for fractional moments of multivariate normal distribution?
$E(\prod_{i=1}^k x_i^{\nu_i})={?}$ where $X=(x_1,\ldots,x_k) \sim N_k(\mu, \Sigma)$, $\nu_i\in \mathcal{R}$ and $\nu_i>0$. I know there is one for univariate normal distributions, but can't find one for the multivariate case.

The formula for the univariate case I know of is
$E[|x-\mu|^{\nu}]=\sigma^{\nu}\frac{2^{\nu/2}\Gamma(\frac{\nu+1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. I understand this is about the central absulate moment, but I am more interested in $E(\prod_{i=1}^k x_i^{\nu_i})$ or $E(\prod_{i=1}^k |x_i|^{\nu_i})$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $|x_i|^{\nu_i}$ instead? It would be worth writing out the analytic formula you like for the univariate case, to show what approximations and what special functions you're comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my question.

Comment: This is now asking for a simultaneous generalization from central to noncentral, from unsigned to signed, and from univariate to multivariate — the combination makes it hopeless to provide a nice formula.

Comment: Thanks. What about the central absolute case $E(\prod_{i=1}^k |x_i-\mu_i|^{\nu_i})$ then? And what if $\nu_i$ are integers?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica gives some results for the bivariate normal distribution with correlation $\rho$ and standard marginals. If $a$ and $b$ are positive integers then

\begin{align}
\text{for odd }a+b,\ \ E[x^a y^b]
&=0
\\
\text{for odd }a\text{ and }b,\ \ E[x^a y^b]
&=
\sqrt{\frac{2^{a+1}}\pi}\
\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac a2\right)
f(a,b,\rho)
\\
\text{for even }a\text{ and }b,\ \ E[x^a y^b]
&=
\sqrt{\frac{2^{a}}\pi}\
\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac a2\right)
f(a,b,\rho)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
f(a,1,\rho)&=\rho \\
f(a,3,\rho)&=3\rho+(a-1)\rho^3 \\
f(a,5,\rho)&=15\rho+10(a-1)\rho^3+(a-1)(a-3)\rho^5 \\
f(a,2,\rho)&=1+a\rho^2 \\
f(a,4,\rho)&=3+6a\rho^2+a(a-2)\rho^4 \\
f(a,6,\rho)&=15+45a\rho^2+15a(a-2)\rho^4 + a(a-2)(a-4)\rho^6
\end{align}
For odd $a$ and $b$ the coefficients appear to be [Ward numbers](http://oeis.org/A181996), and for even $a$ and $b$ they appear to be the [exponential Riordan array](http://oeis.org/A176230).

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.

Comment: These are special cases of Isserlis' theorem, also known as Wick's formula, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem .